# Referencing in java

Tags: java, this

I want the code to output "test in progress ..." but it just outputs "test in". i want to use this. referencing

```
public class Message {
    public String message;

    public Message(String string) {
        message = string;
    }

    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println(message);
    }   

    public Message append(String string) {
        this.message = this.message.concat(string);
        Message updatem = new Message(message);
        return updatem;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Message m = new Message("test");
        m.append(" in").append(" progress").append(" ... ");
        m.printMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `m = m.append(" in").append(" progress").append(" ... ");`

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. `append()` should either mutate or copy, not both.

Comment: Do you know StringBuilder class ? It provide exactly what you attempt to do !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `append` returns a new `Message` object, you need to do as [tsolakp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812787/tsolakp) said:

```
m = m.append(" in").append(" progress").append(" ... ");
```

or change the append method to the return the  instance in:

```
public Message append(String string) {
    this.message = this.message.concat(string);
    return this; // return this instance
}
```